# Tensorflow:Cannot interpret feed_dict key as Tensor

Tags: python, typeerror, tensorflow2.0

I have train a model on CIFAR10 and i want to get the grad of input. So i run the code as follow:

```
tf.compat.v1.disable_eager_execution()

print(tf.__version__)

x = model.input
y = model.output
grad = tf.gradients(y,x)[0]

sess = tf.compat.v1.Session()

result = sess.run(grad,feed_dict={x:train_images[0:1]})
print(result)
```

the version of tf is 2.3.0. I get this error:

TypeError: Cannot interpret feed_dict key as Tensor: Tensor Tensor("conv2d_input:0", shape=(None, 32, 32, 3), dtype=float32) is not an element of this graph.

Please help me, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:
`x = tf.placeholder(tf.float32,(None,32,32,3))`
and add the second line before result var.
`sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())`